# Taking expectation with respect to a probability measure

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, random-variables, expected-value

Let $f$ be a function and $\mu$ be a probability measure. I've frequently seen a notation like: $\mathbb E_\mu[f]$. Does it mean that 
$$
\mathbb E_\mu[f]=\int_\mu f=\int f(x)d(\mu(x))?
$$

I've checked a various sources but only something like (elementary) expectation operator $\mathbb E[X]=\sum_i x_ip_i$ is defined.

Comment: Yes, if $\mu$ is a probability measure.

Comment: In general the notation does not make sense. You should quote the exact context for this.

Comment: The definition you quote for E(X) is for discrete random variables.  The original question assumes f is a function of a random variable with $\mu$ as its probability measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first notation, $\mathbb{E}_\mu[f]$, is correct. The original definition of expectation is basically Lebesgue integral with respect to the measure $\mu$ and can be denoted as $\int f\,d\mu$, or if the integrand needs a variable $x$ to avoid confusion with others, $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$. Usually what is written under the integral sign is for denoting the space which the integral is taken. For example, if one takes integral over the set $K$, it is written $\int_K f\,d\mu$ or $\int_K f(x)\,d\mu(x)$.